# How do I style a ComboBox in Windows Phone 8.1 when there are more than 5 ComboBoxItems?

Tags: combobox, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a ComboBox that is bound to a collection of complex types in my ViewModel which could be any number of length depending on the users' preferences.

I have created a style based on the ComboBox default and all works as expected when there items source count is 5 or below.

However the ComboBox in Windows Phone 8.1 uses the full screen if it has more than 5 items in it's items source.

When this is the case none of my style is being applied and it is using the default ComboBox style.

How can I ensure that the style is applied regardless of the number of items in the ComboBox's items source?

Answer (score 2):

You need to customize the flyout style using the ListPickerFlyoutPresenter. 
Get the default template from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\abi\Xaml\Design\generic.xaml, and apply your preferences.

For example you can change the background and foreground color as following:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ListPickerFlyoutPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Customize your ComboBox by overriding it's property.
Here, let me explain you.

The background of the ListPicker is a binded property, so let's change it's default value

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource PhoneChromeColor}"/>
```

Copy the above code snippet and paste it in your <Application.Resources> of App.xaml

Change the Value of Color to any valid Hex Value and "Voila" the Background color is changed.

Hope you like the detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You must edit "FlyoutButton" object in ComboBox default style. 
When items count is 5 or below "ShortListOuterBorder" is shown as ComboBox template, otherwise it's shown "FlyoutButton".

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" .... >
   ...
</ContentPresenter>

<!-- When items count is more than 5 -->
<Button x:Name="FlyoutButton" ....>
   ...    
</Button>

<!-- When items count is 5 or less -->    
<Border x:Name="ShortListOuterBorder" ....>
   ...    
</Border>
```